# Объединение двух запросов Retrofit правильная реализация

Tags: java, android, list, retrofit

Добрый день помогите разобраться с запросами. Есть два JSON

Первый содержит остатки товара и ключ к складу

```
{
"odata.metadata": "http://server/ocean_shop/odata/standard.odata/$metadata#Collection(StandardODATA.AccumulationRegister_ТоварыНаСкладах_Balance)",
"value": [
{
"Склад_Key": "011cc419-a348-11e7-a211-3085a93c0618",
"Номенклатура_Key": "bb112bd5-e7b4-11e7-a2a9-3085a93c0618",
"ХарактеристикаНоменклатуры_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"СерияНоменклатуры_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"Качество_Key": "d05404a0-6bce-449b-a798-41ebe5e5b977",
"КоличествоBalance": 2
},
{
"Склад_Key": "7dddeeb8-c611-11e7-a22b-3085a93c0618",
"Номенклатура_Key": "bb112bd5-e7b4-11e7-a2a9-3085a93c0618",
"ХарактеристикаНоменклатуры_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"СерияНоменклатуры_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"Качество_Key": "d05404a0-6bce-449b-a798-41ebe5e5b977",
"КоличествоBalance": 3
}
]
}
```

Второй содержит наименования этих складов и ключ к ним

```
{
"value": [{
"Ref_Key": "011cc419-a348-11e7-a211-3085a93c0618",
"DataVersion": "AAAAAAADHyc=",
"DeletionMark": false,
"Predefined": false,
"Parent_Key": "7dddeec0-c611-11e7-a22b-3085a93c0618",
"IsFolder": false,
"Code": "000000001",
"Description": "ТЦ Бачурин",
"Комментарий": "",
"ТипЦенРозничнойТорговли_Key": "f17b4890-a591-11e7-a216-3085a93c0618",
"Подразделение_Key": "99c2e4c6-a655-11e7-a216-3085a93c0618",
"ВидСклада": "Оптовый",
"НомерСекции": 0,
"РасчетРозничныхЦенПоТорговойНаценке": false
},{
"Ref_Key": "7dddeeb8-c611-11e7-a22b-3085a93c0618",
"DataVersion": "AAAAAAADHys=",
"DeletionMark": false,
"Predefined": false,
"Parent_Key": "7dddeebf-c611-11e7-a22b-3085a93c0618",
"IsFolder": false,
"Code": "000000003",
"Description": "На Льва Толстого",
"Комментарий": "Первоймай качай ! А Хабаровск ввсех рввет))",
"ТипЦенРозничнойТорговли_Key": "f17b4890-a591-11e7-a216-3085a93c0618",
"Подразделение_Key": "7dddeeb6-c611-11e7-a22b-3085a93c0618",
"ВидСклада": "Оптовый",
"НомерСекции": 0,
"РасчетРозничныхЦенПоТорговойНаценке": false
}]
}
```

Как можно реализовать запрос который бы выдавал бы значения типа

```
ТЦ Бачурин 2
На Льва толстого 3
```

Я пытаюсь сначала получить значение реально ли этот товар существует на складе и передаю их адаптеру а как привязать наименования склада у меня не хватает фантазии. По сути нужно формировать второй запрос который бы доставал мне наименования склада по ключу но как это реализовать более правильно и без нагромождения кода я не знаю. Я только начал изучать разработку приложений под Android поэтому прошу не судить строго))

```
private void getNomenclatureAllProducts(final NomenclatureActivity inflater, String guid){
// inflater контекст
// guid интересующий меня товар
        ServisAPI api = RetrofitClient.getApiService();
        Call<AccumulationRegisterGoodsOnWarehouses> accumulationRegisterGoodsOnWarehousesCall = api.getAllProducts(guid);
        accumulationRegisterGoodsOnWarehousesCall.enqueue(new Callback<AccumulationRegisterGoodsOnWarehouses>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<AccumulationRegisterGoodsOnWarehouses> call, Response<AccumulationRegisterGoodsOnWarehouses> response) {


                valueList = response.body().getValue();

                adapter = new CatalogNomenclatureAmountAdapter(inflater, valueList);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<AccumulationRegisterGoodsOnWarehouses> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Я бы пошел одним из двух путей: 1. В сущность 1 клал бы сущность 2. Или создал бы одну сущность которую бы наполнял из обоих JSON, смотря что Вам нужно по задаче.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю как это можно реализовать. Может есть пример?

Comment: Мне нужно на экран вывести ТЦ Бачурин 2
На Льва толстого 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для реализации взял только необходимые данные.

Суть:
Преобразовываете свои JSON в объекты, в своем случае подвел Ваши данные под массив.
В Вашем случаем нужно под объект с полем value типа или массив или List.

В итоге получаете два списка: Остатки и Склады.

А вот далее от того что вам нужно.

Я в примере преобразовал данные в карты и вывел данные из складов на основе данных из остатков.

Вы же можете перебрать и просто инкапсулировать объект Storage в класс Rest, если Вам необходима дальнейшая связь данных объектов в приложении.
Или же вообще можете сделать объект с поляим id, Rest, Storage и наполнить его данными, тогда будет один объект.

Пример кода по получению объектов ниже. Использовал GSON.
Важно! Пример тестовый, так чо не стоит на него смотреть как best practice.

```
    import com.google.gson.Gson;

    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;
    import java.util.stream.Stream;

    public class JsonTest {


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();

            Rest[] rests = gson.fromJson(FirstJson.json, Rest[].class);
            Storage[] storages = gson.fromJson(SecondJson.json, Storage[].class);

            Stream.of(rests).forEach(r -> System.out.println(r.getId() + " : " + r.getCountRest()));
            Stream.of(storages).forEach(s -> System.out.println(s.getId() + " : " + s.getDescription()));

            Map<String, Rest> restMap = Stream.of(rests).collect(Collectors.toMap(r -> r.getId(), r -> r));
            Map<String, Storage> storageMap = Stream.of(storages).collect(Collectors.toMap(r -> r.getId(), r -> r));

            System.out.println("========================");

            restMap.forEach((s, r) -> {
                System.out.println("id: " + s);
                System.out.println("\tdescription: " + storageMap.get(s).getDescription());
                System.out.println("\tcount: " + restMap.get(s).getCountRest());
            });
        }
    }


    class FirstJson {
        public static String json =
                "[{\"Склад_Key\":\"011cc419-a348-11e7-a211-3085a93c0618\",\"КоличествоBalance\":2},{\"Склад_Key\":\"7dddeeb8-c611-11e7-a22b-3085a93c0618\",\"КоличествоBalance\":3}]";
    }

    class SecondJson {
        public static String json =
                "[{\"Ref_Key\":\"011cc419-a348-11e7-a211-3085a93c0618\",\"Description\":\"ТЦ Бачурин\"},{\"Ref_Key\":\"7dddeeb8-c611-11e7-a22b-3085a93c0618\",\"Description\":\"На Льва Толстого\"}]";
    }


    import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

    public class Rest {

        @SerializedName("Склад_Key")
        private String id;

        @SerializedName("КоличествоBalance")
        private int countRest;

        public Rest() {
        }

        public Rest(String id, int countRest) {
            this.id = id;
            this.countRest = countRest;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public int getCountRest() {
            return countRest;
        }
    }


    import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

    public class Storage {

        @SerializedName("Ref_Key")
        private String id;

        @SerializedName("Description")
        private String Description;

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return Description;
        }
    }
```